# How to show all of the packages names in a terminal?

Tags: 16.04, apt, server, aws, putty

I'm using a AWS/EC2 ubuntu server from my computer and I'm new to this and I have only a command line interface to use that ubuntu server, while logging in there's a message I get to see 31 packages can be updated, so I want to know what are those packages and their names so that I can update manually one by one according to my choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `apt list` with the option `--upgradable` displays the list of upgradeable packages:

```
$ apt list --upgradable
```